# How to load state on app startup using provider

Tags: flutter

I am using Provider for app state management in Flutter, Auth data is stored in shared preferences and I want to load it using provider when app starts, what is the best way to do it.

I am going to use auth status to decide whether user should see login screen or Dashboard screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final appState = await loadAppStateFromSharedData();

  runApp(
    Provider.value(
      value: appState,
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is part of a code i used when i started flutter, implement rest of the functions as you wish.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './providers/authentication.dart';

MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Authentication(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Authentication>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          home: auth.isAuthorized
              ? MyScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  future: auth.tryLogin(),
                  builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                      authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : AuthScreen(),
                ),
```

authentication.dart

```
String _token;
DateTime _expiryDate;
String _userId;

 bool get isAuthorized {
    // that is a very simple check
    return token != null;
  }

Future<bool> tryLogin() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('userData')) {
      return false;
    }
    final extractedUserData = json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')) as Map<String, Object>;
    final expiryDate = DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate']);

    if (expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return false;
    }
    _token = extractedUserData['token'];
    _userId = extractedUserData['userId'];
    _expiryDate = expiryDate;
    notifyListeners();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I have found to the problem of loading app data on app startup. ChongeNotifierProvider and future builder combination is working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'AppName',
          home: auth.isAuth
              ? DashboardScreen()
              : AuthScreen(),
        ),
      ),
  };
}
```